# NullReferenceException:Model.get returned null

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I got a very weird NullReferenceException. It's weird because the page is displayed correctly(with data) without exception, until I go right click>Inspect the page and then I get NullReferenceException. Even I'm checking first if the CartOrder is null or not, plus to make sure CartOrder has items.

The exception is showing on line **if(Model.CartOrder != null)** .

```
  @{ 
        var totalQt = 0;

        if(Model.CartOrder != null)
        {
            if (Model.CartOrder.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.CartOrder)
                {
                    foreach (var order in item.Orders)
                    {
                        totalQt = totalQt + order.Quantity;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        <h3 class="cart-num-of-items">Cart <span class="cart-num-counter">(@totalQt items)</span></h3>
    }
```

Error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage<TModel>.Model.get returned null.
```

Comment: Try again, Add `?` in your if, `if(Model?.CartOrder != null)`

Comment: That solved my problem. The view model doesn't have any optional parameters, what can cause this issue? btw Thank you!

Comment: Is because you `CartOrder` is null, if is string, use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, example `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model?.CartOrder))`

Comment: But if the CartOrder is null, the data won't be displayed. However, all data is there until I try to inspect the page. That's why I try first to check if it's not null and .Count() has some data then show the data. Anyway, thanks! :)